# How can I reset the index within an each loop after the index has hit a specific number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops, indexing

I know the title sounds complicated but what I am trying to achieve should be quite simple.

Ok so let's say that you are using a jQuery each loop to loop through anything (*doesn't matter what*). Then after a specific iteration you want the loop index to reset and start recounting back up instead of just counting up. How would you achieve this?

So for the sake of this example I just made a simple list item that I am looping through and **after the 4th iteration I want the index to go back to 0 and count up again instead of 5 , 6 , 7 ,8 , 9**

**JSfiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/b9de1xr0/

In my JSfiddle above you'll see the index within the loop being logged out into the console like so **0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ,5 ,6 ,7 ,8 ,9**. Now I am trying to make it so that after the index is greater than 4 the index within the loop will restart and show up like so **0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4**

How can I achieve this?

**My Simple Javascript:**

```
$('li').each(function(i){
    if(i <= 4){
    console.log(i);
  }
  if(i > 4){
    console.log(i); //want it to restart the index back at 0 here
    }
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: @gyre shouldn't be an infinite loop since it's only iterating as many times as there are elements (which is 10 li elements)

Comment: I misunderstood your intention. I thought you wanted to restart the loop instead of logging a different pattern with the indexes. See my answer below.

Comment: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/b9de1xr0/1/) is this what you want to get?

Comment: You can't restart `i`, it is a callback argument, you don't control it, in this case `jquery` does

Comment: Since it doesn't really need to be the index then you can just declare a counter and reset it to 0 on the 5th iteration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using the modulo (`%`) operator:

```
$('li').each(function (i) {
  i %= 5
  console.log(i)
})
```